# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Tags: vue.js, storybook

I'm using @storybook/vue to make my storybook and I'm trying to embed a view component in my mdx files but I get these errors:
"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')" and "The above error occurred in the component".
I've followed the documentation and searched on different forums but I can't find it.

my code :
button.docs.mdx

```
import { Canvas, Meta, Story } from '@storybook/addon-docs';
import Table from "@/stories/stories-component/Table.vue";

<Meta title="Bootstrap Custom Button Documentation" />

# Test

<Canvas>
    <Story name="test table">
        {() => {
            return {
                components: { Table },
                template: `<Table></Table>`
            };
        }}
    </Story>
</Canvas>
```

Table.vue

```
<template>
    <p>test component </p>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name:"Table",
    props: {}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not seeing it in the code you posted but somewhere there is a reference where the id is being called. something like variablename.id.  try to identify that code.

Comment: Apparently it's the <Story> component that doesn't detect the ID, I searched several repositories for the solution and they all write the story component like this:
<Story name="...">{{ template: `...` }}</Story> but it's always the same error

Comment: Solution found, it's because my file had this format component.mdx instead of components.stories.mdx